# Are there methods to instruction prefetch in software?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, x86-64, prefetch

I have a particular function call. The first instruction of the function is missing in the instruction cache more often than I'd like. Due to the places where the instruction/function is called from, code layout optimization is not a great idea. These insights come after extensive profiling and execution trace analysis.

Is there any way to prefetch for the instruction cache in software? Something like `__builtin_prefetch(&function)`. But that is for data cache - can I induce a prefetch for the instruction cache in the source code?

To be clear, calling the function will give me something like `call 0x555` in the assembly, where `0x555` is the address of the function, and I want to ensure `0x555` it is in the instruction cache before `call 0x555`.

Comment: Standard C and C++ don't have any such thing, so you're looking for implementation-dependent functions.  What compiler / architecture?

Comment: This would be under QEMU, so actually ideally the architecture would be flexible. But for now, let's say x86. And the compiler is GCC.

Comment: Note many machines have unified L2/L3 cache, so data prefetch may still be better than nothing.  I'm not aware of any icache prefetch functionality on x86.

Comment: That's a good point - I did notice even with the data prefetch (putting it in L3), the miss ratio went down a bit.

Comment: I'd add the `x86-64` tag to your question, someone like Peter Cordes may have some good insights about this

Comment: Other architectures might, though, e.g. ARM64 has the `PRFM PLI*` family.  Note that with regard to QEMU, a separate question is whether the emulator actually does any prefetching or if it just ignores the hint.

Comment: Looks like this question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571263/bring-code-into-the-l1-instruction-cache-without-executing-it

Comment: @WBuck: Yes, but note that the use-case there was to prime things for a microbenchmark, *not* as part of getting an *overall* speedup.  If you just want that, prefetch into L2 cache with a standard data prefetch would probably be better, since the answer on the linked duplicate involves intentionally causing a branch mispredict, as well as probably an I-cache miss.  (Although the I-cache miss can be in a mis-speculated branch so it doesn't have to stall for it.)  I added [X86 prefetching optimizations: "computed goto" threaded code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46321531) to the dup list

Comment: Possibly also related: [Cost of a 64bits jump, always 10-22 cycles the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39682209)